# openssl passwd md5 hash is wrong?

Tags: openssl, base64, md5

Many of my friends are switching to Linux these days, but they don't have much knowledge of what a command would do. So, I help them set up their desktop, which includes installing several packages. I can exploit this privilege to get access to their password,
example:

> $ sudo apt install vim && sudo cat /etc/shadow

Of course, the password is hashed, but I'm aware that the password is 8 characters long and I can limit the number of characters used in password to about 15, which makes the problem solvable.
The problem begins here, I'm getting different hash from

> $ openssl passwd -1 -salt 'CEJ.3nql' hello 
> $1$CEJ.3nql$3B.yeC2E8Bq/Fq5PrbgFg/

and

> $ echo -n 'helloCEJ.3nql' | openssl md5 -binary | openssl base64 
> DH2HkMrkhYrERBmtzWwY1A==

So, I don't understand why the output of first command is different, it uses md5 hashing algorithm, since the hash is 22 'characters' long, I assume it is base64 encoded, although I have reasons to believe it isn't base64, since the hash contains '.' character which shouldn't appear from base64, but I'm out of choices here. What is the problem here?
PS: I'm not trying this on my friends, it's just a problem I thought of

Comment: If memory serves, $ is not in base64, so the output from the first command is not base64 encoded?

Comment: @Grismar I think $ is just used to mark separation of hashing algorithm, salt and the hash, the hash given by first command is 3B.yeC2E8Bq/Fq5PrbgFg/ and that is my question, if not base64, then what?

Comment: nvm, found the answer to the question. The encoding used is B64, character set './0-9A-Za-z', using crypt library in python works for me